How to estimate the parameters in this accelerometer calibration model?
I'm using the xioTechnologies Fusion AHRS library to estimate orientation from readings from a 6-axis IMU. The library provides functions to apply calibration parameters according to this calibration model:

where $i_c$ are the corrected $x$, $y$, and $z$ accelerometer readings, $M$ is a misalignment matrix, $s$ is a sensitivity diagonal matrix, $i_u$ are the uncorrected accelerometer readings and $b$ are the accelerometer offsets.
The library does not provide functions to estimate the calibration parameters, nor an explanation on how they can be estimated. I'm trying to figure it it myself but I can't quite work it out.
As a first step I can assume $s$ is the identity matrix so the model simplifies to $i_c = M(i_u -b)$ but from there I'm stuck. I know I need to take readings of $i_u$ in all six orientations for which I know $i_c$. I think the parameters can be estimated using OLS but I'm unsure how to do that exactly because of the $-Mb$ term.
I found this question with the same model but the first answer stops before explaining how to exactly estimate the parameters. The second answer uses an alternative model that combines the $M$ and $b$ parameters in one matrix and I'm not sure how to retrieve the original parameters from that alternative model.
I hope someone can point me in the right direction.
